# how to import aws-synthetics with ES6 syntax

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-cloudwatch-synthetics

Have a code of tests that should be automated in jenkins,
and some config files like this:

```
import synthetics from 'Synthetics';

const stepConfig = {
  continueOnStepFailure: false,
  screenshotOnStepStart: false,
  screenshotOnStepSuccess: true,
  screenshotOnStepFailure: true,
};

export const executeStepWithConfig = async (
  stepName: string,
  step: () => Promise<void>,
  config = stepConfig
) => await synthetics.executeStep(stepName, step, config);
```

etc

in jenkins job I run "npm install" command to install dependencies and additionaly
sh "npm install @aws-cdk/aws-synthetics".

The question is:
in https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-cdk/aws-synthetics?activeTab=readme it is mentioned only ES5 import syntax like `const synthetics = require('Synthetics')` and I got this output in console
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kugu2.png)
because im my code `import synthetics from 'Synthetics'` is used, so how to do to make it work with  import with ES6 syntax?

Expecting to make it work whithout changes to the code